# Boxing off texts in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTML so I wasn't sure how to go about finding the answer on how to do this but basically I am trying to box off a certain chunk of text and indent and fill in the background color for only a small section(not all the way across the width of the webpage) like this:[boxing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j32wa.png)

Comment: can use `background-color` and `margin`?

Comment: yeah I can use background-color..idk about margin. I think so though. I know how to change the background color for one part but I dont know how to restrict it to not going across the entire page. like it should only cover the area with texts (much like the textbox function in microsoft word)

Comment: you can use `class` for that.. so all boxes coontain the same `css format`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
//HTML
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
</div>

//CSS
.content {padding: 20px; background-color: #333}
.content p {background-color: #eee; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 10px}
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qszx5uwh/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main_container">
   <div class="box1">text for box 1</div>
   <div class="box2">text for box 1</div>
   <div class="box3">text for box 1</div>
</div> <!--main_container ends here-->

<style type="text/css">
.main_container{float:left;width:500px;}
.box1{float:left;width:500px;background:#cc0000;}
.box2{float:left;width:500px;background:#cccccc;}
.box3{float:left;width:500px;background:#f1f1f1;}
</style>
```

Comment: Use the SO Code Editor so that we can run the snippet and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

All you'll need is text wrapped with text-wrapper for setting paddings and background-color.

```css
.text-container{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis odit, placeat repellendus ab sint dolore aut itaque earum molestias laudantium dolor nostrum nihil aperiam eos illum quia tempore beatae voluptate.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis odit, placeat repellendus ab sint dolore aut itaque earum molestias laudantium dolor nostrum nihil aperiam eos illum quia tempore beatae voluptate.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis odit, placeat repellendus ab sint dolore aut itaque earum molestias laudantium dolor nostrum nihil aperiam eos illum quia tempore beatae voluptate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```